# How do I update single item using Signal R and ASP.Net Core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a model called Server, with the following attributes

1. ID
2. ComputerName
3. Type
4. State
5. Phase (0 to 100)

The attribute Phase is the one that needs to be updated in real time with signal R.
In order to have a visual of my website, here is what I have so far:

[image]

The phase attribute is described in the progress bar. Depending on the value of the attribute phase, the progress bar will be "filled".
However, I'm having some problems with this. When I make a API call (using Postman) with the PUT method, that changes the Phase value, the progress bar does not update, it ends up duplicating what is already there with the new phase value:

[image]

Here is my code:
PUT Method:

```
 [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutServer(int id, Server server)
        {
            if (id != server.ID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var serv = _context.Server.FirstOrDefault(serverId => serverId.ID.Equals(id));
            if(serv != null) 
            {
                serv.Phase = server.Phase;
                serv.ComputerName = server.ComputerName;
                serv.Estado = server.Estado;
                serv.Type = server.Type;
            
            }


            //_context.Entry(server).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


                var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                      .WithUrl("http://localhost:53043/myHub")
                      .Build();

                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("PostServers");
                await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ServerExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
```

Here is my Hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public  async Task PostServers() 
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateServers");
        
    }
}
```

Here is the html and javascript code:

```
<div id="progressDIV"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// var indicator = document.getElementsByClassName("progressIndicator")
//.innerHTML = text;
var progress = 0;
var progressDiv = document.getElementById("progressDIV");
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/myHub").build();

connection.on("UpdateServers", function () {
    $.get("/api/ServersAPI", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {


            console.log(item.phase);

            //CREATE DIV WITH SERVER NAME
            var serverNameDiv = document.createElement("div");
            serverNameDiv.id = "serverName";
            var serverName = document.createTextNode(item.computerName);
            serverNameDiv.appendChild(serverName);
            progressDiv.appendChild(serverNameDiv)



            // CREATE DIV THAT CONTAINS THE STATUS AND PROGRESS BAR
            var container2 = document.createElement("div");
            container2.className = "container2";

            // DESCRIPTION OF PHASE
            var progressDescription = document.createElement("p");
            progressDescription.className = "progressIndicator";


            //CREATE PROGRESS BAR 
            var progressBar = document.createElement("div");
            progressBar.className = "progress";
            var myProgressBarDiv = document.createElement("div");
            myProgressBarDiv.className = "myProgress bar bar-danger";
            progressBar.appendChild(myProgressBarDiv);

            container2.appendChild(progressBar);

            progressDiv.appendChild(container2);


            var bar = document.querySelector(".myProgress");
            bar.style.width = item.phase + "%";

            var description;

            if (item.phase < 30) {
                description = "Preparação do servidor...";
                bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped active";
            } else if (item.phase >= 30 && item.phase < 70) {
                description = "Instalação dos updates...";
                bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active";
            } else if (item.phase >= 70 && item.phase < 80) {
                description = "Restart ao servidor...";
                bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active";
            } else if (item.phase >= 80 && item.phase < 100) {
                description = "Últimas verificações...";
                bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active";
            } else if (item.phase == 100) {

                description = "Concluído";

                bar.className = "progress-bar progress-bar-success";
            }


            progressDescription.textContent = description
            container2.appendChild(progressDescription);

            container2.appendChild(progressBar);

            progressDiv.appendChild(container2);


            atualizaBD(item.ID, item.computerName, item.type, item.estado, item.phase)

        });


    });


});

connection.start().then(() => {
    connection.invoke("PostServers").catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

});



function atualizaBD(idserver, computername, type,estado, phase) {
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: `/api/ServersAPI/${idserver}`,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ID: idserver,
                ComputerName: computername,
                Type: type,
                Estado:estado,
                Phase: phase
            }),
            async: true,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                connection.invoke("PostMarker").catch(function (err) {
                    return console.error(err.toString());
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert(phase)
            }
        });
}
```

How can I make this update in real time and also just updating the value of the phase?
I'm available to share more code if needed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you can read this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/april/cutting-edge-discovering-asp-net-core-signalr . And in this document contains source code link:https://github.com/despos/ProgCore/tree/master/Src/Extras/SignalR1

Comment: Thank you very much, It looks like this has what I need!